# Unable to catch SSLHandshakeException in Jira Client

Tags: java, rest, jira, jira-rest-api, jira-rest-java-api

I am not able to catch the SSLHandshakeException within the catch block and suspect it to be the asynchronous nature of AsynchronousJiraRestClientFactory. Any thoughts on getting it right. I want to execute a retry operation on catching the exception.

```
    try {
        URI jiraServerUri = URI.create(uri);

        JiraRestClientFactory factory = new AsynchronousJiraRestClientFactory();
        JiraRestClient restClient = factory.createWithBasicHttpAuthentication(jiraServerUri, username, password);

        return restClient;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Caught exception ", e);
        throw e;
    }
```

Comment: Is it not coming inside catch block ?

Comment: @Sambit It's not reaching the block hence raised the query.